# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following database schema in my rails 4 application

Users >---Tags_users---< Tags >---Posts_tags---< Posts

given the currently logged in user, what is the best way for me to get all of the posts (from all users) that match there tags the tags that they are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array to `Model#where` to get an array of posts with the choosed criteria.

```
def show_by_tags
  @posts = Post.all
  array_of_tags.each do |tag|
    @posts.where(tag_name: tag)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I meant. I'm looking to select posts the user may be interested in based on the tags they have selected

Comment: this gives me the error...
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column posts.tag_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."tag_id" IN (SE... ^ : SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."tag_id" IN (SELECT "tags"."id" FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "tags_users" ON "tags"."id" = "tags_users"."tag_id" WHERE "tags_users"."user_id" = $1)

it looks like rails doesn't recognize my many to many relationship, there isn't supposed to be a post.tag_id, i've created a posts_tags table with FK's to both posts and tags

Comment: You have a join table called: posts_tags? Edit the question to show more info, like the models related and the relations.

Comment: Try this to filter by each tag name in the array. Replace tag_name by the attribute to filter.